# Navbar not appearing as a child element of the body in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating this website using create-react app. The code structure for the pages is as follows -

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="root">
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed-top topBar"></nav>
        <div id="mainBody"></div>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I inspect this page through Chrome Dev Tools, on hovering over the html element the entire page is highlighted but when I hover over the body or the 'root' div, it doesn't highlight the navbar. I don't get why this is happening because structurally the navbar is inside the body and the 'root' div. I'm using the create-react-app and have noticed some other react apps I found online also seem to have this problem.

I'm not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help?

Comment: take nav otside of div with id root

Comment: `<nav>...</navbar>` check your markup

Comment: @LazarNikolic that doesn't help

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan sorry that's a typo. I've edited it

Comment: Create React App uses div with id root to insert into that element all of the app. Your manually inserted nav and mainBody div are part of your html file and not CRA. I don't think you should be adding elements like this in CRA.

Comment: @LazarNikolic I haven't done that. This code snippet is to explain the structure which is why it is plain HTML. The full code is a part of the App.js file which is imported as a component into the index.js files which renders everything into the index.html file. I'm not directly adding anything.

Comment: r u using bootstrap?

Comment: @DEEPAK yes I am.

Comment: this could be coz of class fixed-top which doing positioning in css , try without using those classes

Comment: @DEEPAK I made some changes to the classes of the nav element and made some few other changes. It is working as it should now. Still don't get what really happened here though!

Comment: ````fixed-top````  have css ````postion:fixed; top:0;```` so it will stuck to top , regardless with the body

Comment: @DEEPAK yes but body is the parent div here. It should show as a part of the the root and body divs. I don't see how fixed-top interferes with that